# Managing concurrent promises in Node.js using task queues，What is causing my Node.js code to exceed the expected number of requestingPages?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have written the following Node.js code which uses a pool object and a page.goto function. However, the requestingPages property of the pool object reaches over 35, which is beyond my expectation. Can anyone help me identify what is causing this issue? Here is the code I am using:

```
page.goto = (async function (url, options) {
    if(this.pool.requestingPages > 30){
        await new Promise((resolve) => {
            this.pool.waitList1.push(resolve);
        });
    }
    this.pool.requestingPages++;
    let result;
    try{
        result = await pageGoto(url, options);
        this.pool.requestingPages--;
        if(this.pool.waitList1.length > 0){
            let resolve = this.pool.waitList1.pop();
            resolve();
        }
    }catch(e){
        this.pool.requestingPages--;
        if(this.pool.waitList1.length > 0){
            let resolve = this.pool.waitList1.pop();
            resolve();
        }
        throw new Error('goto error');
    }
    
    return result;
})
```

I appreciate any help in identifying the cause of this issue.

I am confident that I have not modified the value of this.pool.requestingPages anywhere else. Can anyone help me understand why this is happening and how to correctly write code for controlling concurrent page requests?

Comment: seems to work as expected ... https://jsfiddle.net/m9zohv0u/

Comment: The only thing with this approach is, that the first request that is sent to the `waitingList` will be handled last. And if there is a steady flow of new requests, it might even stay on the queue forever, because it's a LIFO. Instead of `pop` I'd suggest to use `shift` which removes the *first*  element from the array instead of the last ...